# How to redirect to new page when image is clicked? (html)

Tags: html

I am trying to setup this html code so that when someone clicks on this image they will be redirected to a new url. For some reason when I click the image it redirects the image to google.com and not the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/ssLtf588/

I have the src set to the image which i assume is the error. How should i go about changing this?

```
<div class="container">
<a href="http://google.com">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SSPyEQ3.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Hello World Whats up!</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. It redirects the image to google.com.

Comment: I don't want the image to display google.com I want the entire browser tab to be redirected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `target="_blank"` if you want it to open in a new window..

Here you go:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ssLtf588/2/

On your fiddle, the `a` tag is behind the overlay, so when you click, it's a click on the overlay and not on the link.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm using a site called Wix.com and for some reason it opens up google when i click on it inside this html box app. So, it literally opens up google inside the image app and not the actual browser tab. Is this the fault of wix? Is there anyway around this?

Comment: You have to use Javascript and use an Iframe with google on it, but I don't know if wix allow javascript..

Comment: My javascript is done before the html code but it all runs properly on wix's html app thing.

Comment: Send the link please

Comment: I thought my javascript was the first portion of code on jsfiddle but i'm begginging to think it actually isnt.